# ng-options doesn't work in select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, ng-options

I'm trying to implement a select in my angular app to show data about tv show episodes in a table.

In the select the user should be able to select one of the episodes.

I tried by `ng-repeat` the option elements, which worked. But when I try to set `ng-options` for the select, they seem to be not recognized.

Any idea, what I got wrong here?

Here is my html:

```
<div class="container-fluid full-height">
    <div id="tabs_container" class="col-xs-12">


        <div ng-app="seriesAnalyzer" ng-controller="configTableController">
            <label>
                Episode:
                <select>
                    <option ng-repeat="episode in all_episodes | orderBy:['season_number','episode_number']">Season: {{episode.season_number}} Episode: {{episode.episode_number}}</option>
                </select>
            </label>

            <!-- This is not working -->
            <label>
                Episode:
                <select ng-options="episode.season_number for episode in all_episodes track by id">
                    <option value="">Please select an episode...</option>
                </select>
            </label>

            <div ng-init="episode = episode_data">
                <p>{{episode_data.episode_number}}</p>
                <p>{{episode_data.season_number}}</p>
            </div>

            <table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
                <thead></thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="scene in episode_data.configuration_matrix">
                    <td ng-repeat="values in scene track by $index" ng-style="set_color(values)" >{{values}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>

        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
seriesAnalyzer.controller('configTableController', function ($scope, $http) {

var req_url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/episodes';
$http.get(req_url)
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.all_episodes = data;
        console.log($scope.all_episodes);
    })
    .error(function (data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });


$scope.update_season_number = function(){
    console.log(val);
};

$scope.update_episode_number = function(){
    console.log("Input changed");
};

var get_episode_data = function()
{
    var req_url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/episodes?season_id=' + $scope.season_number + '&episode_id=' + $scope.episode_number
    $http.get(req_url)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.episode_data = data;
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};

....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
<select ng-options="episode as episode.season_number for episode in all_episodes track by episode.id" ng-model="selectedEpisode">
    <option value="">Please select an episode...</option>
</select>
```

More info can be found on the [ng-options documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

And here is an [example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptp6gbsy/) as well (using Angular 1.5.1)

Also `track by episode.id` might not work for your version of Angular so you might have to remove it

In case you need both season number and episode number then do the following:

```
<select ng-options="episode.season_number + ' ' + episode.episode_number for episode in all_episodes track by episode.id" ng-model="selectedEpisode">
    <option value="">Please select an episode...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This works for me, but I need season_number and episode_number to be shown like "Season 1 Episode 2". How can I do this?

Comment: @Igle `episode.season_number + '  ' + episode.episode_number for episode in all_episodes track by episode.id`

Comment: @Igle you can also `group by`  `episode.season_number`

Comment: @Igle np mate, just in case you need to group your data by season check this fiddle with a similar example http://jsfiddle.net/arzdeck1/ -